# Maven clean plugin error pushing changes to openshift project

Tags: maven, openshift

I tried to push some changes in open shift project but I get this error every time, tired to create a new project or to kind of force the clean of the project by adding some code to pom.xml its refusing to work..

Build log :

```
    [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.4.1 from/to nexus (http://mirror.ops.rhcloud.com/nexus/content/groups/public): Failed to transfer file: http://mirror.ops.rhcloud.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom. Return code is: 503, ReasonPhrase:Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build' for /var/lib/openshift/543020b45973ca088d00003d/jbossews

For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
```

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>services</groupId>
 <artifactId>services</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <name>services</name>
 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>eap</id>
   <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
   <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </releases>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
 </repositories>
 <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>eap</id>
   <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
   <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </releases>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </pluginRepository>
 </pluginRepositories>
 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.25</version>
  </dependency>     
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
 <groupId>asm</groupId>
 <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
 <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
 <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
 <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
 <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
 <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
 <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
 <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
 <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
 <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
 <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
 <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

 </dependencies>
 <profiles>
  <profile>
   <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
    invoking mvn. -->
   <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
    will need. -->
   <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'webapps' 
    folder. -->
   <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
   <id>openshift</id>
   <build>
    <finalName>services</finalName>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
      <configuration>
       <outputDirectory>  webapps</outputDirectory>
       <warName>ROOT</warName>
      </configuration>
     </plugin>


    </plugins>
   </build>
  </profile>
 </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing the same thing, I think their repos are down.

I get "File Not found" on

http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom

And some others, even though they are in maven central

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom